# a popover won't show inside a form it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hello guys i am new to web developping so the problem may be obvious , the popover won't show inside a form when i click on input , it works fine in the exemple but in my code it doesn't

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input  type="text"  name="name" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Popover Header" data-trigger="focus">name</input>
```

Comment: Where are your `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: Is the code provided the example, or the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: i didn't put them on the exemple below but as i told you i think the problem comes from the form layout

Comment: There is no content in your popover

Comment: Atleast try to create a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryWVl.png)
i'm using another version of jquery for the range slider i think that might be the problem